# How to return catchable error to the ajax call in Struts 2?

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

I have some Struts 2 actions called by Ajax. I try to deal with error and catch the error but it doesn't work as expected.

the method ajax method:

```
deleteIndicateur(id) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "DELETE",
   url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/mesures.ce.delete.action?id=" + id,
   success: function (resp) {
    alert(resp);
   },
   error: function (resp) {
    alert(resp);
   }
 })
},
```

and this `Action`:

```
        @Action(value = "ce.delete", results = {
                @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"root", "indicateurDictionnaire"}),
                @Result(name = "error", type = "json", params = {"root", "errors"})
        })
        public String delete() {
            Integer dicId = Integer.valueOf(this.getParameter("id"));
            try {
                dicBo.delete(dicId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.errors = getText(e.getMessage());
                return ERROR;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

Delete works fine but when the method has an error, the error is catch by the success function in the ajax request. How I must do to return a catchable error to the Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `error` is called if the response has a status code corresponding to the error.  See [the list of HTTP status codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

To return a response with error messages and setting the status code corresponding to the error needs to configure the action result `error`. Similar to

```
@Result(name = "error", type = "json", params = {"root", "errors", "statusCode", 400})
        })
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, indeed it works. I added this to the params : params = {"root", "actionErrors", "statusCode", "400"} now it goes to the error and I can send the error message from the action.